# DevOps Continuos Delivery for Java Script

Tags: devops

Can i use Jenkins integration for DevOps Continuos Delivery Pipeline for JavaScript code builds?
I am trying to build/propose a solution for integrating Jenkins tool and to remove manual code build and deployments to remove the manual effort for my team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Jenkins, you can use the below:

Build -> Automated Test -> Dev Deploy -> QA Approval -> QA Deploy

The Seed Job is the one which will be creating other Jenkins job automatically but the seed job itself will be configured manually. The Seed Job will read the DSL script, parse those and create appropriate Job configurations in Jenkins.

After the seed job runs successfully, we will have a job created for our sample app.

The Seed job will create the following set of jobs which will eventually be part of the pipeline. The Seed job will also create a Jenkins pipeline view.

Build:  This job includes the configuration for the building project, job triggers, scm location, jdk version to use, maven goals, artifact upload to repo like Artifactory.

Test: This job can call test suites and decide to call a downstream job or not.

Dev Deploy: Simple job with a trigger to the Promotion Job if the deployment was successful.

This job can call the script to perform a deployment or use tools like Bamboo or Urbancode.

Usually a Dev deploy doesn’t need promotion, but we can add that step if required.

QA Promotion: This job includes a send email notification to the person/group responsible for approval. The email contains a link for promotion.

The Promotion Email link can look like this:  http://localhost:8080/XXX/XXXXX/XXX

The same can be done for the UAT and Prod:

We can chain multiple Promotion Jobs and Deploy jobs to accomplish the need for another environment, for e.g. UAT Promotion -> UAT Deploy ->PreProd Promotion -> PreProd Deploy -> Prod Promotion -> Prod Deploy

And here for all the above mentioned processes it can be done via Jenkins tool

Also yes, to answer your question you definitely can use Jenkins integration in Devops Pipeline.

If you are building your solution in cloud or in any domain servers then you might have to get the Jenkins integrated in the same environment.

Comment: Thanks , Well explained. @Deblina